# Bad performance in elasticsearch with many text fields

Tags: elasticsearch

My environment:

Ubuntu 16.4, CPU 16 cores, 16 GB Memory, SSD disk.

200 text fields.

I have one node.

We use 4 threads with bulk API and partial updates.

We see that the GC Duration is ~150 ms, is it normal?

Can we increase the indexing rate (current is ~2000 s)? Because we don’t see any bottleneck on CPU and Disk.

[image: kibana monitor 1]
[image: kibana monitor 2]

Comment: When u are only indexing and dont need to query the data yet, u can set the index refresh time to -1 so it wont refresh the index while indexing. You will need to set it back to your desired index refresh time once the index is finished. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html

Answer (score 0):

first of all, GC duration under  200ms is normal. 
for more indexing speed, you can set refresh interval to -1 and number of replica to 0. 
also you should test bulk size. try to increase and decrease the bulk size and check whether the indexing speed has change. 
more information:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html